# Angular 4 - Conditional *ngFor that displays every 3rd element

Tags: angular, loops, ngfor

I have an ngFor loop where I want it to only iterate through every 3rd element in the array, like i'd expect the below code to work:

```
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i=i+3)...
```

My current ngFor code looks like:

```
<md-card class="cardContainer" *ngFor="let viz of visualisationList; let i = index">
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-title>{{ viz['Title'] }}</md-card-title>
        <md-card-subtitle>Datasets: {{ viz['Datasets'] }}</md-card-subtitle>
    </md-card-header>
</md-card>
```

Is there an easy way to do this within the ngFor loop?  I can pre-filter into 3 arrays using typescript within the ngInit(), or I could use ngIf and a modulo function, but I was hoping I could do it directly within the ngFor loop.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and in my opinion cleanest way would be to filter the array inside your component's logic by using `Array.filter` and a getter like this:

```
public get filteredArray() {
    return this.array.filter((value, index) => index % 3 === 0);
}
```

And use the filtered array for your `ngFor`.

**Note:** If your array is decorated with as an input it may be `undefined`, you should initialize it with an empty array or check inside the getter if it's undefined before using the `filter` method.

Comment: I figured that this way was easy enough, but I was still hoping to do it within the HTML.  Even if I don't go down the HTML path, I still wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: It would  be possible with a combination of `ngFor`, the index and `ngIf`, but you should keep your "logic" out of the template whenever you could.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a `Pipe` filter for that. However you still need to define it make it known to the component. There's an inbuilt [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe), which is not what you want but quite similar. Based on that I would guess you could use:

```
@Pipe({name: 'thirdelement', pure: false})
export class ThirdElementPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    if (value == null) return value;

    if (!this.supports(value)) {
      throw invalidPipeArgumentError(ThirdElementPipe, value);
    }

    return value.filter((v, i) => (i % 3 == 0));
  }

  private supports(obj: any): boolean { return typeof obj === 'string' || Array.isArray(obj); }
}
```

And use it like

```
<md-card class="cardContainer" *ngFor="let viz of visualisationList | thirdelement; let i = index">
```

Or even a more generic `SkipPipe`:

```
@Pipe({name: 'skip', pure: false})
export class SkipPipeimplements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, amount: number): any {
    if (value == null) return value;

    if (!this.supports(value)) {
      throw invalidPipeArgumentError(SkipPipe, value);
    }

    return value.filter((v, i) => (i % amount == 0));
  }

  private supports(obj: any): boolean { return typeof obj === 'string' || Array.isArray(obj); }
}
```

This should be usable like

```
<md-card class="cardContainer" *ngFor="let viz of visualisationList | skip:3; let i = index">
```

Comment: Interesting approach - I've never seen anything like that before.  But I'm guessing from your response that there is nothing Angular native within ngFor that may allow me to do what I am trying to do.  I'd rather just write a function that returns an array with the correct elements than go down this path - but thank you for the interesting approach.
I should have specified within the question that I was looking for something that ONLY requires the modification within the HTML.

Comment: I don't know of a a pure HTML approach, besides for example filtering with `*ngIf="i%3==0"` in `<md-card-header>`.  However while the pipe approach needs some javascript you only need to define that pipe once in your module. After that you can use it in all templates of the module. Which depending on your use-case might be worth it or not.

Comment: Love the new approach and still learnt something new with it, but unfortunately, it wasn't what I was looking for in the question.  Thanks for the new knowledge though.

Comment: The `FilterPipe` is one of the anti-patterns in Angular2, FYI. Read here for more information: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0):

You could move the ngFor up one level to an ng-container and use ngIf/modulo on the md-card, but I think it's better to prepare your data before it gets to the view, personally.

Comment: Yeah I know.  Wanted to know if it was possible to do it all directly within the ngFor loop.  I know you can add if-then-else conditions to an ngFor loop, but I am yet to see anything like this.